# How can I add a margin note right next to a table?

Tags: tables, marginpar, marginnote

I would like to add a margin note right next to a table as shown below:

[image: Desired structure of table and margin note]

Unfortunately the margin note appears at the bottom of the previous page although the table is located (correctly) at the top of the following page.

Here's my code:

```
\marg{Margin note}
\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    \begin{tabular}{|p{10cm}|p{4cm}|}
        \hline
        \rowcolor{tableHeaderColor}
        \textbf{Header1} & \textbf{Header2}\\
        \hline
        Test & Test\\
        \cline{1-2}
        Test & Test\\
        \hline
        Test & Test\\
        \hline
        Test & Test\\
        \hline
        Test & Test\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}
    \caption{Capture}\label{tab:FlickerFrequencies}
\end{table}
```

The command behind `\marg{}` is:

```
\newcommand{\marg}[1]{\marginpar{\raggedright \textbf{#1} }}
```

I also tried to take the margin note inside the table-environment, but there I got errors.

Could anyone help me with this problem? Thanks in advance!

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt, final, twoside, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[{left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=0cm,bottom=0cm}]{geometry}

\newcommand{\marg}[1]{\marginpar{\raggedright \textbf{#1} }}    


\begin{document}
        
    \newgeometry{left=2cm,right=2cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm,headsep=1.5cm, marginparwidth=1mm,marginparsep=3mm,includeheadfoot}
    
    Lorem\marg{Lorem} ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    \\
    
    Lorem\marg{Lorem} ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    \\
    
    Lorem\marg{Lorem} ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    \\
    
    Lorem\marg{Lorem} ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    \\
    
    Lorem\marg{Lorem} ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    \\
    
    Lorem\marg{Lorem} ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    \\
    
    Lorem\marg{Lorem} ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    \\
    
    \marg{Margin note}
    \begin{table}[H]
        \centering
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
        \begin{tabular}{|p{10cm}|p{4cm}|}
            \hline
            \textbf{Header1} & \textbf{Header2}\\
            \hline
            Test & Test\\
            \cline{1-2}
            Test & Test\\
            \hline
            Test & Test\\
            \hline
            Test & Test\\
            \hline
            Test & Test\\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}
        \caption{Capture}\label{tab:FlickerFrequencies}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: use package newmatrix which has tikz associated with it

Comment: Does it matter which side the margin note goes? Should it always be on the right hand side, for example?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE... Can you post your `MWE` as in compilable format? i.e., from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`

Comment: @Werner The margin notes should change the side on every page (which is also working for the rest of the document).

Comment: @MadyYuvi I added a MWE in the question above

Comment: @user230754 Do you need the table caption strictly at the bottom?

Comment: While \marginpar cannot go inside a float, \marginnote can, so when the table moves (cannot fit on the current page), a \marginnote will move with it.

Comment: @MadyYuvi Yes, I need it at the bottom

Comment: @JohnKormylo \marginnote works for the note of the table, but now other margins are shifted outside the page. I'll have to solve this problem later, now I have some other, more important, stuff to have to get working. Thank you anyway for your help.

Comment: Thanks you all for your help